# dropdown button of bootstrap does not work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

The dropdown code I copied from the first example at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/
But it does work as there. I use Bootstrap v5.0.0-beta2. I paste all of my code in the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="jQuery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.esm.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown button
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the boostrap.min.js and popper.min.js scripts for the dropdown to work.

Dropdowns are built on a third party library, **Popper.js**, which provides dynamic positioning and viewport detection. Be sure to include **popper.min.js** before Bootstrap’s JavaScript or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper.js. Popper.js isn’t used to position dropdowns in navbars though as dynamic positioning isn’t required.

[Boostrap Dropdowns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)

Comment: Yes, I included them by the code ```   <script src="jQuery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.esm.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>``` But it still does not work.

Comment: try place the Javscript files after the </body> tag

Comment: Somehow still does not work. While if I replace the Bootstrap css and js files by version 4.6.0, it works (no matter where do I put the scripts). So I guess there is some problem in the 5.0.0 beta version.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem of Bootstrap itself. When I changed back to v4.6.0 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/download/ it works.

Answer (score 0):

BS-v5 without jQuery --> `Bootstrap Bundle with Popper` 
So you can use only one file include and check like below snippet.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>BS-v5</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container py-1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1>Bootstrap v5.0.0-beta2</h1>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown button
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 
<!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add your script tags **before** your closing `</body>` tag, not after it or at the start of `body`

But also use the jsDelivr method on the bootstrap homepage

https://getbootstrap.com/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown button
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```